# What is the IO Haskell Monad equivalent in Scala standard API?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, io-monad

I know there are some almost identical implementations in Scalaz of IO operators like `putStrLn :: String -> IO (`) and `getLine :: IO String` but I mean about Scala standard API why there aren't such equivalents?
I know Scala is not a pure language as Haskell and there is side effect but I consider that this datatype is so descriptive and useful.
I don't know if `Try`, `Option` or `Either` would do the job.

Comment: As a Haskeller, I'd tend to agree. However, Scala has Java interoperability as a main selling point, and I'm not surprised if some conventions are inherited (like not marking the `IO` effects at the type level). I think one could define a custom `IO` monad in Scala, if wanted -- perhaps it would not be that useful (since IO effects can be performed anywhere), except as a form of documentation. Perhaps such `IO` would be a glorified identity monad, in Scala, or a "lazy" monad instead?

Comment: Relevant: ["IO Monad" considered harmful](https://blog.jle.im/entry/io-monad-considered-harmful.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala has implicit ambient side-effects, just like C♯, Java, C++, Objective-C, Swift, C, Pascal, Basic, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ECMAScript, etc. There is no type for `IO`.

There are third-party libraries that provide an `IO` type, but it doesn't give the same guarantees as Haskell's: Haskell has only a very few escape hatches (`unsafePerformIO`), in Scala, pretty much *everything* is an escape hatch.

However, there are ideas and I believe even research prototypes for effects systems in Scala, and the streamlined, more powerful, and sound type system of Dotty is probably going to be an even better foundation for that.

Answer (score 8):

Scala's standard library has no IO monad.  Libraries like Monix, Scalaz, FS2, and now Cats provide IO monads (or Task with concurrency support).  If you want to haskell type programming you will need one of these libraries, especially Cats or Scalaz which also other useful tools and typeclasses (such as actual functor and monad type classes).

Comment: Scalaz' ones are `scalaz.effect.IO` in `scalaz-core` package and `scalaz.concurrent.Task` in `scalaz-concurrent` package for concurrent variant.